# ios - How to mock a method with pmkpromise as the return type

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock, promisekit

I have method which I want to unit test:

```
- (void)fetchInfo {
[AMKAccountService getInfo]
.then(^(AMKInfoResponse *response) {

    if (response.accounts.count > 0) {
        _viewModel = [[AMKInfoViewModel alloc] initWithInfoResponse:response];
        [self.view setAsOfDate:_viewModel.asOfDate];
    } else {
        [self.view showError:[AMKStrings feedbackForCode:@"testError"]];
    }
}).catch(^(NSError *error) {
    DLog(@"Error getting info: %@", error);
    [self.view showError:[AMKStrings feedbackForCode:@"testError"]];

});
```

}

In this method, 'getInfo' method makes a service call and returns response of type PMKPromise object.

My question is how to mock the getInfo method and make the 'then' block called for one unit test and 'catch' block called for the other unit test.

[Update]
Here's getInfo method:

```
+ (PMKPromise *)getInfo {
AMKServicesClient *client = [AMKServicesClient sharedInstance];

return [client GET:@"/amk-web-services/rest/info" parameters:nil].thenInBackground(^(NSDictionary *responseDictionary) {

    return [[AMKInfoResponse alloc] initWithResponse:responseDictionary];
});

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the `getInfo` method? I briefly looked at PromiseKit and from what I found (https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=PMKPromise) I can't immediately see where `then()` is defined. I would assume that it's a property that returns a block but I'd have to see what the types are exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your response Erik. I have updated my question and have added the getInfo method.

Comment: What have you tried? What does your test case look like?

Answer (score 1):

In order to test this, you will have to either break the dependency between `getInfo` and the shared `AMKServicesClient`, or set up some sort of system that allows you to load a mock services client when `[AMKServicesClient sharedInstance]` is called.